# netbeans plugin update constantly freezes at 50%

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I've been trying to update my netbeans plugins ever since 7.0.1, but I've never been able to get beyond half of the installation bar. It just freezes at around 50% each time. After I close the IDE, it will attempt to update but fail. I've updated to 7.1 but the issue still persists even for the initial Junit plugin installation after a fresh installation of 7.1.

I've attached a screenshot. Does anybody know what is the issue here?

[image: netbeans]

Comment: In `View->IDE Log`, do you see some errors here?

Comment: nope. only INFO and WARNING only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read in the Definitive Guide to NB Platform 7.1 that you have to install NetBeans (well because of the JUnit) into the folder, where it has write rights. Which is not the Progam Files in Windows 7. 
So try to install it for example into C:\Programs or something like that. You can install new version (7.1.1) even without uninstalling the older one and then let the NB get your previous settings (it will ask).

Comment: Hmm okay I'll try installing it in my D drive and see how it goes.

Comment: Well I still got the "pause at 50%" problem even after installing in a non-restricted partition. However, the plugins installed without a hitch when I ran Netbeans with administrator privileges. So your post definitely helped. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I could for the first/second time help somebody:-).

Answer (score 1):

You can try temporarily disabling your firewall and/or antivirus. I got the same problem, and disabling AVG Internet Security everything worked fine. Hope it helps!

Comment: That helped me also. Disabling AVG for update time solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in network. So try to change network you are on. I am using university network that has many policies and only JUnit plugin installation stucks. Went to local wireles public network and JUnit plugin was installed successfully.

Comment: Nope that was not the issue for me. I couldn't install it on both my home and university network. The accepted answer did help me with my installing though. See the comments. (: